# ios insert custom emoji icons with custom keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, emoji

I'm using **ios 8** and i want to insert custom emoji icons with my custom keyboard.

How can i create my custom emoji with unicode?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Nope. You can't create custom emoji icon. Just you can do custom keyboard consisting of icons and use copy - paste @Bhumit

Comment: any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585189/custom-keyboard-add-multiple-emoji-icons-while-long-press-on-keyboard-button

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to create custom emoji with unicode just like what Apple and Android are using. But as mentioned by Koray you can use your own images and then copy and paste it to your sender when image is tapped.

```
let pb = UIPasteboard.general
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: imageName))
pb.setData(data!, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePNG as String)
```