# Custom Keyboard - Add multiple emoji icons while long press on keyboard button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, custom-keyboard

Anyone having an idea how to create a custom view for multiple emoji icons, while user long press on the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: You need to draw the layout using `UIBezierPath` and do addSubView as well.

Comment: @iphonic. Thanks for guidance. Any reference link or sample code?

Comment: I am sorry I don't have any sample code, as I never tried it. But this is the way you have to do, [see this](https://github.com/mindbrix/TurtleBezierPath) for how you can draw layout, its seems simple to do, bit of programming and calculation needed. Good Luck.

Comment: thanks let me check that

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can find all the details and some raw Obj-C code [here (gist)](https://gist.github.com/w-i-n-s/8340df38da7d3e1144ff7e26a475c678). The code isn't complete but enough to start.

Here only draw background image code:

```
- (UIImage*)hintImage {

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPoint p = CGPointMake(__PADDING_X, __PADDING_Y);
    CGPoint p1 = CGPointZero;
    CGPoint p2 = CGPointZero;
    //1
    p.x += __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

    NSUInteger hintCount = [self.hintSymbolsList count];
    //!!!:magic numbers
    self.hintAdditionalWidth = 2*(hintCount-1)*(self.frame.size.width+__GAP_X);

    //2
    p.x += __PAN_UPPDER_WIDTH + self.hintAdditionalWidth;
    //!!!:+hintCount*(__PAN_LOWER_WIDTH+__GAP_X);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

    //3
    p.y += __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                 p.x, p.y,
                 __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS,
                 3.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 4.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 false);
    p.x += __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;

    //4
    p.y += __PAN_UPPER_HEIGHT - __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    if (self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionFarRight ||
        self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionRight) {
        p.y += - 2*__PAN_UPPER_RADIUS + __PAN_CURVE_SIZE + __PAN_MIDDLE_HEIGHT;
    } else { //ACHintPositionLeft & ACHintPositionFarLeft
        p.y -= __PAN_CURVE_SIZE;
    }
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

    if (self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionFarRight ||
        self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionRight) {
        //5.1
        p.x -= __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
        CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                     p.x, p.y,
                     __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS,
                     4.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     1.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     false);
        p.y += __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;

        //5.2
        p.x -= self.hintAdditionalWidth + __PAN_UL_WIDTH-2*__PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

        //5.3
        p.y += __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
        CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                     p.x, p.y,
                     __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS,
                     3.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     2.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     true);
        p.x -= __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    } else { //ACHintPositionLeft & ACHintPositionFarLeft
        //5
        p1 = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y + __PAN_CURVE_SIZE);
        p.x -= __PAN_UL_WIDTH;
        p.y += __PAN_MIDDLE_HEIGHT + __PAN_CURVE_SIZE*2;
        p2 = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y - __PAN_CURVE_SIZE);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL,
                              p1.x, p1.y,
                              p2.x, p2.y,
                              p.x, p.y);
    }

    //6
    p.y += __PAN_LOWER_HEIGHT - __PAN_CURVE_SIZE - __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS;
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);
    //7
    p.x -= __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS;
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                 p.x, p.y,
                 __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS,
                 4.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 1.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 false);
    //8
    p.x -= __PAN_LOWER_WIDTH;
    p.y += __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS;
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);
    //9
    p.y -= __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS;
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                 p.x, p.y,
                 __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS,
                 1.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 2.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 false);
    //10
    p.x -= __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS;
    p.y -= __PAN_LOWER_HEIGHT - __PAN_LOWER_RADIUS - __PAN_CURVE_SIZE;
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

    if (self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionFarRight ||
        self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionRight) {
        //11
        p1 = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y - __PAN_CURVE_SIZE);
        p.x -= __PAN_UL_WIDTH;
        p.y -= __PAN_MIDDLE_HEIGHT + __PAN_CURVE_SIZE*2;
        p2 = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y + __PAN_CURVE_SIZE);
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL,
                              p1.x, p1.y,
                              p2.x, p2.y,
                              p.x, p.y);
    } else { //ACHintPositionLeft & ACHintPositionFarLeft

        //11.1
        p.x -= __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
        CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                     p.x, p.y,
                     __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS,
                     4.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     3.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     true);
        p.y -= __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;

        //11.2
        p.x -= self.hintAdditionalWidth + __PAN_UL_WIDTH-2*__PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

        //11.3
        p.y -= __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
        CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                     p.x, p.y,
                     __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS,
                     1.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     2.0*M_PI/2.0,
                     false);
        p.x -= __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    }

    //12
    p.y -= __PAN_UPPER_HEIGHT - __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    if (self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionFarRight ||
        self.hintPosition == ACHintPositionRight) {
        p.y += __PAN_CURVE_SIZE;
    } else {
        p.y -= - 2*__PAN_UPPER_RADIUS + __PAN_CURVE_SIZE + __PAN_MIDDLE_HEIGHT;
    }
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);

    //13
    p.x += __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS;
    CGPathAddArc(path, NULL,
                 p.x, p.y,
                 __PAN_UPPER_RADIUS,
                 2.0*M_PI/2.0,
                 3.0*M_PI/2.0,
             false);
    //----
    CGContextRef context;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(__WIDTH+self.hintAdditionalWidth,
                                       __HEIGHT));
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, __HEIGHT);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextClip(context);

    //----

    CGRect frame = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);
    CGColorRef backColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, backColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, frame);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CFRelease(path);

    return image;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12655508)

Comment: @Keiwan Now it is ok?